# how to move GraphicsPath onMouseMove

Tags: c#, winforms, transform, graphicspath

am using `GraphicsPath` to draw `Lines` so it's like `Pen/Brush` tool in `Paint`

```
   public void OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        start = e.Location;
        path.AddLine(e.Location, new Point(e.Location.X, e.Location.Y));
    }

    public void OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        end = e.Location;
        path.AddLine(e.Location, new Point(e.Location.X, e.Location.Y));
    }

    public void OnMouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        end = e.Location;
        path.AddLine(e.Location, new Point(e.Location.X, e.Location.Y));
    }

    public void OnPaint(object sender, Graphics g)
    {
        g.DrawPath(pen, path);
    }
```

how would I `Relocate` it , I have tried `Transform` method , but it didn't work..

```
 public void Relocate(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Matrix m = new Matrix();
        m.Translate(start.X + e.X - end.X, start.Y + e.Y - end.Y, MatrixOrder.Append);
        path.Transform(m);

    }
```

so how would I do it the right way? moving the whole drawn shape?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

- Separating logic for creating line and moving line? I think you would need it in your implementation to differentiate which operation you are doing.
- When moving the line, the `path` can be transformed via your `Relocate()` method and the following should be sufficient:

  ```
  Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
  matrix.Translate( offsetX, offsetY ); //Where offset is the new location
  path.Transform( matrix ); //Transform the path
  ```

Then do not forget to redraw the `path` via `Invalidate()`

Comment: am separating the logic of-course , and I have tried that  `matrix.Translate( offsetX, offsetY ); ` where the new offsets are the mouse location , but that is not working correctly!

Comment: _the new offsets are the mouse location_ of course they should be the distance to the last position..!

Comment: @TaW and how would I get the distance?

Comment: You need to keep track of the previous position!